# Face Detection and tracking using android vision

Tags: android, face-detection, android-vision

I am trying to make a simple app to instruct the user (audio instructions) when a face is detected and based on the happiness level tracked. I use [FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) as the base for my program.

I am not able to identify when a face is detected and where can I insert the audio instructions in the face detected pipeline. I mean how the control flows in the pipeline.

Could somebody please suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Tracker class in the API, which you extend for callbacks when the face is initially detected, updated, and leaves the frame.  For example, FaceTracker has the following code:

```
private class GraphicFaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onNewItem(int faceId, Face item) {
        mFaceGraphic.setId(faceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
        mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
        mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
    }
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java#L280

I think what you'd want to do is to call your code for the audio instructions in the onUpdate method, based on the values passed in for the associated face.

This tutorial discusses the control flow of the pipeline for the face tracker app:

https://developers.google.com/vision/face-tracker-tutorial#creating_the_face_detector_pipeline

In your case, if you are only tracking a single user, you probably want to use LargestFaceFocusingProcessor rather than the MultiProcessor used in the face tracker example.  The difference is that LargestFaceFocusingProcessor is specialized for tracking only one face (i.e., the user) rather than multiple faces.  Setup would go something like this:

```
Tracker<Face> myTracker = new Tracker<Face>() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
        // issue audio instructions
    }
};

detector.setProcessor(
    new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor.Builder(detector, myTracker).build());
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely reply, @pm0733464 . I was really stuck at that point. Yes.. You are right, I dont need to capture multiple faces, LargestFaceFocusingProcessor  should do for my purpose. Let me go try it out .

Comment: When I added a TTS object to speakout some text(audio) , on OnUpdate, it stopped tracking faces!! I have tried even OnNewItem too. Doesnt know why!!

Comment: You probably need to launch TTS in a separate thread.  I'm guessing that the call that you are making is blocking, which means that the face tracking pipeline won't resume until it returns.

Comment: Let me try launching TTS as a separate thread and see.. Thanks for your inputs.